# On careers replies have the option of not willing to re-locate

Tags: feature-request, jobs

On the Careers site when you receive a message and reply with no interested option can "not willing to re-locate" be added as an option.

I ask as 90% of message I have to enter this response. I understand this is currently covered by this position is not quite what I am looking for however I feel it would give more feedback to employers.

Comment: The bigger win is for employers to not message you to begin with if this is your preference.  It's harder, so if we can't succeed there we'll implement your suggestion.  We're on it.